# How to categorize test case failures in jenkins logs

Tags: python, machine-learning, jenkins, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am using jenkins pipeline job for running automation scripts.
I am generating a report in text and html format.
We have a test case count of 500+ test cases and post successful jenkins job completion we get a count of passed and failed test cases.
Due to a huge count of test cases it is a very cumbersome task to analyse the failures.

Is there any way to categorize these failures and get a summary of the failures? For eg: x count of failures due to element not found exception, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using NLP and AI to classify and cluster the text from failure messages, why not try to organize test cases logically? So you would group tests for module A in `tests/tests_module_a/`, tests for module B in `tests/tests_module_b/` and so on. Then when you run your tests you get an overview of the tests and which ones failed.

With pytest-cov you can have a coverage report generated, e.g. as xml and use this for your further analysis.

Furthermore, if you have 500+ test cases it might be wise to start splitting the application.